Motor amp surging
I want to power a 5 ton Package AC unit with a generator.  Most likely it will be 3ph at 380v. To have reliability of the AC fan motor and compressor motor so I need to protect them with a surge load suppression of some sort? I am not sure what is needed if anything but was told that in this setup the PAC AC will not last powered by a Generator.
Any help would be appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
